# How to make excel addin for distributing excel macro

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have two Excel macros in my personal workbook which I use with a combination of keys.

Now other users want to have these macros and use them with a combination of keys. I have found information that the easiest way is to create an Excel addin and they have to install it.

What is the process of creating this excel addin with my two macros, and then how can I install it to other users?

We are using Excel 2013.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new file

Copy your macros to the new file

Save the new file as Excel-Addin (*.xlam)

Distribute the Excel-Addin

On the other PC Go to Excel -Options - Addins

Add the botton choose Excel-add-ins press goto

Search for the addin file and tick it

Comment: Also, if working with a server,  you may want to click 'No' when asked if you want to copy it to the local add-in folder. By doing so, you can overwrite the network version with updates / extended functions for all users without having to redo the process. And depending on the nature, build a Ribbon bar with buttons for the functions (using Custom UI Editor, for example).. People tend to be forgetful with shortcut codes